# swig-generated code links to wrong python installation

Tags: python, macos, gcc, swig, macports

I have the following problem,

I'm building a python module using swig to wrap C-code. 
I have installed python, gcc(45),.. using MacPorts.

Here's a minimal setup which reproduces the problem:

Two files:

test.i:

```
%module test
double sum(double a, double b);
```

test.c:

```
double sum(double a, double b){return a+b;}
```

I run

```
$ swig -python  -I. test.i
$ gcc -fPIC -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c test_wrap.c
$ gcc    -c -o test.o test.c
$ gcc -shared -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -lpython -dynamiclib -fPIC -o _test.so test.o test_wrap.o
```

When I run python (the MacPorts one: /opt/local/bin/python2.7) and try to import the module via `import test`, the code crashes with exactly the same problem as above.

Examining the file _test.so with otool yields the following:

```
$ otool -L _test.so
_test.so:
   _test.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.2)
   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1669.0.0)
   /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

I found out that in the swig-generated file test.py the line `#include <Python.h>` is contained. However there is a Python.h in /System/Library/... and one in /opt/local/...
My guess is that the mistake is happening here. But how can I make the compiler/linker point to the correct one?

Thanks a lot for any help!!
Thomas

Comment: I found the answer, instead of `-I/opt/local/Library... -lpython ` , use `-F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/ -framework python`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a mac, but I have good results by using distutils to deal with multiple Python versions on Linux and Windows when using swig ([swig doc](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn6) and  [distutil doc](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-source-files)). The following shows a minimal example of a setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup,Extension
ext = Extension('_test',sources=['test.c,test.i'])
setup(name='test',ext_modules=[ext],py_modules=["test"])
```

Distutils is binding to the calling python version and knows about swig. However, it is important to compile by:

```
python setup.py build_ext
python setup.py build_py
```

And not calling build directly.